# Cumulative distribution function and limit

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let CDF of the random variable $X$ is $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\le0.5\\(x-0.5)^2,0.5\lt x\le 1.5\\1,x\gt 1.5\end{cases}$$

What is the CDF of $Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X^n}{1+X^n}$?

I don't know what will be when $0.5\lt x\lt1.5$. In this case $0\lt(x-0.5)\lt1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X^n}{1+X^n}=\frac{0}{0+1}=1$.

Thus,
$$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0,y\le0.5\\1,0.5\lt x\lt 1.5\\0.5,x\ge 1.5\end{cases}$$

Is this correct? The new CDF is discontinuous.

Comment: The function $F_Y$ that you defined is not even a CDF. Note that $Y$ can only take values in $\{0,\frac12,1\}$ (provided that $X$ does not take value $-1$). It is up to you to find the corresponding probabilities $P(Y=0), P(Y=\frac12), P(Y=1)$. Once you know them then you can also find the CDF of $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y$ has pointwise limit
$$
Y(\omega) = \begin{cases}
0,& \omega\in X^{-1}(1/2,1)\\
\frac12,& \omega\in X^{-1}(\{1\})\\
1,& \omega\in X^{-1}((1,3/2)).
\end{cases}
$$
Since $X$ is continuous, $\mathbb P(X=1)=0$. Further, $$\mathbb P(Y=0) = \mathbb P(X\in(1/2,1)) = F_X(1)=(1-1/2)^2 = \frac14$$
and
$$\mathbb P(Y=1) = \mathbb P(X\in(1,3/2)) = F_X(3/2)-F_X(1) 1 - \frac14 = \frac34.$$

It follows that $Y$ has cumulative distribution function
$$
F_Y(y) = \frac14\cdot\mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(y) + \frac34\cdot\mathsf 1_{[1,\infty)}(y).
$$

Comment: Can you clarify why $Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}$, when $x=1$ and what is $1_{[0,\infty]}$?

Comment: $\frac{1^n}{1+1^n}=1$ for all $n$, and $\mathsf 1_A$ denotes the indicator function; i.e. $\mathsf 1_A(x)$ equals one if $x\in A$ and zero if $x\notin A$.

Comment: @Math1000 You meant to say that $\frac{1^n}{1+1^n}=\frac12$ for all $n$.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo; thanks.

Comment: @Math1000, can you further explain how you get $F_Y(y)$?